# IntelliJ IDEA Scala inspection : import play.api.xxx conflict with com.company.play package

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I want to make a helper class at the root of my `core` project using play-json from typesafe, something like

```
package com.company

import play.api.libs.json.JsValue

object Helper {

  implicit class RichJson(json: JsValue) {
    def doStuff() //...
  }
}
```

The problem is that I have somewhere else in the project a package com.company.play

```
package com.company.play

class Foo() { //... 
}
```

In IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4 CE, the line `import play.api.libs.json.JsValue` is in error with telling me "cannot resolve symbol api" and when Ctrl+Click on the `play` it goes to the folder containing my Foo.scala file

If I compile the solution with sbt outside of IDEA, there is no problem.

If I put the `Helper` object in a subpackage (eg `com.company.common`) there is no error (which also means the dependency is correct in my build.sbt)

I don't understand why IDEA miss this, `com.company.play` isn't even in the dependencies of the `core` project. I already tried to invalidate cache, and it doesn't help.

Comment: Try `import _root_.play.api.libs.json.JsValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Intellij gives precedence to the package `play` into your project, instead of the package coming from the framework, when resolving the import of `JsValue` inside `com.company` scope.

If you really want to keep that name for `com.company.play`, there is a simple workaround using a fully-qualified import, just prefix like this:

```
import _root_.play.api.libs.json.JsValue
```